# How do I make this block go back to the left with another click?

Tags: c#, unity, 2d

This is the script I've written so far which makes the block move from the left of the screen to the right on a mouse click. What I want to achieve is for the block to move back to the left when I click the mouse again. So I can have a back and forth movement with each mouse click. Thank you for any help it's much appreciated.

```
public class PlayerControls1 : MonoBehaviour  {

private bool hasBeenTapped = false;
private bool control = false;
public float speed = 20f;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        hasBeenTapped = true;
            }

    if (hasBeenTapped && transform.position.x < 4 && control == false){
        transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(transform.position.x > 4.0f) {

        control = true;

        hasBeenTapped = false;
    }

    if(hasBeenTapped && transform.position.x == 4 || transform.position.x < 4 && control == true) {
        transform.Translate (-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(transform.position.x < -4){

            control = false;

            hasBeenTapped = false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic answer

```
public class PlayerControls1 : MonoBehaviour  {

private bool hasBeenTapped = false;
private bool shouldMoveLeft = false;
private bool control = false;
public float speed = 20f;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        hasBeenTapped = true;
            }

    if (hasBeenTapped && !shouldMoveLeft && transform.position.x < 4 && control == false){
        transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (hasBeenTapped && shouldMoveLeft && transform.position.x > 0 && control == false){
        transform.Translate (Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(transform.position.x > 4.0f) {
        transform.position.x = 4.0f;
        control = true;
        shouldMoveLeft = true;
        hasBeenTapped = false;
    }

    if(transform.position.x <= 0.0f) {
        transform.position.x = 0.0f;
        control = true;
        shouldMoveLeft = false;
        hasBeenTapped = false;
    }

    if(hasBeenTapped && transform.position.x == 4 || transform.position.x < 4 && control == true) {
        transform.Translate (-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(transform.position.x < -4){

            control = false;

            hasBeenTapped = false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You would be wise to keep a state of this object. Then decide on the behavior based on the state and the input from the user.